# Выводиться неправильный результат

Tags: c++, borland

Составьте программу, которая для целого числа k (от 1 до 30), введенного
вами, напечатает фразу « Мне k лет», где k - введенное число, при этом в
нужных случаях слово «лет», заменяя на слово «год» или «года». (Например:
при k=70 « 70 лет», при k=15 «Мне 15 лет», при k=23 «Мне 23 года» и т. п.

Задание простое, НО, почему код неправильный:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
void main()
{float k;
 printf("Vvedite k ");
 scanf("%f",&k);
 printf("Mne "); printf("%f ",k);
 if(k=1,11,21){
 cout<<"god";
 }else if(k=2,3,4,22,23,24){
 cout<<"goda";
 }else if(k=5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,25,26,27,28,29,30){
 cout<<"let";
 }
getch();
}
```

В чём проблема: всё время выводиться слово "god"! Уже по моему всё перепробовал и не получается всё равно. В чём ошибка?(знаю, код выглядит ужасно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так нельзя:

```
if(k=1,11,21)
```

Вы, судя по всему, имели в виду

```
if(k == 1 || k == 11 || k == 21)
```

В вашем коде вызывается (совершенно ужасный, на мой вкус) [оператор «запятая»](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), поэтому ваш код равносилен такому:

```
k = 1; // присвоение, а не сравнение
11;    // бесполезное пустое выражение, компилятор тем не менее
       // глотает такое -- ещё одна историческая особенность языка
if (21) // числа, не равные 0, неявно приводятся к true -- ещё одна особенность
```

В общем, вы пробежались по аккуратно разложенным в языке граблям.

Comment: Тооочно, спасибо большое) А в инете ничего по этому поводу не сумел найти

Comment: @Treaq, просто любопытно,

а какие  именно вопросы в инете Вы задавали?

Comment: Я бы Вашу задачу решил используя % и switch-case

Answer (score 2):

```
void main(){
int k;
printf("Vvedite k ");
scanf("%d", &k);
printf("Mne %d ", k);
if (4 < k && k < 21)
    printf("let");
else{
    k %= 10;
    if (k == 1) printf("god");
    else if (1 < k && k < 5) printf("goda");
    else printf("let");
    }
}
```